# Is $V_a=\{a+y\mid y\in W\}$ a subspace of $V$ with the law $(a+x)+(a+y)=a+(x+y)$ and $\lambda (a+x)=a+\lambda x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ a $K-$ vector space and $W$ a subspace of $V$. Let $a\notin W$ and define $$W_a=\{a+w\mid w\in W\}.$$
I proved that $W_a$ is not a subspace of $V$ (since at least, $0\notin W_a$). Let define $$(a+x)+_A(a+y)=a+(x+y)\quad \text{and}\quad \lambda \cdot _A(a+x)=a+\lambda x,$$
where $x,y\in W$ and $\lambda \in K$. So, now, $(W_a,+_A,\cdot _A)$ is a vector space.

**My questions:**

- Does $(W_a,+_A,\cdot _A)$ is a subspace of $V$ ? It sounds weird for me, because the structure on $V$ and on $W_a$ is not the same.
- If not, what is the connection between $V$ and $(W_a,+_A,\cdot _A)$ ? May be $(W_a,+_A,\cdot _A)$ is a subspace of $(V,+_A,\cdot _A)$ ? But I don't see in what $(V_a,+_A,\cdot _A)$ would be interesting.

Can someone enlighten me on the interest of $(W_a,+_A,\cdot _A)$ and the connexion with $V$ ?

Comment: Maybe $a \notin W$ in first line?

Comment: @DiegoG7: I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: $W_a$ is isomorphic to $W$

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a vector subspace of $V$ (unless $a = \vec{0}$). By definition, to be a vector subspace, the operation has to be the one coming from $V$ (e.g. the sum of two vectors has to be the sum in $V$): this is not the case here.

The subset $W_a$ is however what is called an [affine subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Affine_subspaces_and_parallelism). In fact that's one possible definition of an affine subspace: a vector subspace shifted by a vector.

The structure $(+_a, \cdot_a)$ you have defined is not part of the structure of an affine subspace, though. Instead what you have done is [transported the structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure) of the vector space $W$ along the bijection $W \to W_a$, $w \mapsto a + w$. Moreover it is true that $W_a$ is a subspace of $V_a$. How interesting that is is up to you... Maybe it shows that the notions of "vector space" and so on do not just depend on the underlying set but also the structure you put on it.